# Can we use AWS Cloudfront error settings to force refresh an SPA

Tags: angular, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

### Background:

Our initial architecture had a single Angular application on a single URL, `login.example.com`. As our requirements grew, we split our functionality into two separate applications:

- App A to handle authentication

  - This would sit on the 'old' URL `login.example.com`
- App B to serve content. Users would be redirected to this after authentication

  - This would sit on a new URL `app.example.com`

We are using AWS S3 + Cloudfront to host / serve both applications.

### The issue:

We migrated to the new architecture in late Nov, but some users are still seeing the old application on `login.example.com`, we assume because of browser caching.

### Steps taken to resolve (so far):

- Invalidating our Cloudfront instances
- Loading `safety-worker.js` https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#safety-worker

### Possible new approach:

Cloudfront provides the error page options in the screen grab below. One option seems to be:

- Change the name of the `index` file in our Angular application to `index2.html` and update `angular.json`
- Redeploy our application.
- Delete `index.html` from the S3 bucket
- Update our Cloudfront settings to redirect any errors to `index2.html` and invalidate the files

What are the risks of this approach and will it force browsers to load the new application on `login.example.com`?

If not, are there other approaches we could take (short of migrating to a completely new URL).

[image]

Comment: You're mixing up or misusing a lot of terminology.  A "refresh of an SPA" typically refers to a browser refresh, not "cache bust".  If a browser is caching something and you specified it to have a very long `max-age` and you haven't built in cache busting mechanisms using ETag and the Last-Modified headers the CDN likely isn't going to help you because it's not going to bother refetching assets because you told it not to bother.  Invalidating the CDN wasn't going to help you unless you set the cache extremely long and it would have refreshed itself anyways.

Comment: If you need more help, it would be *extremely* important to post information on what you have set up for browser caching to begin with.

Comment: I'd be the first to admit I'm not a devops expert - hence the question :)

Let's assume I've done nothing special to facilitate "cache busting" but also nothing to specify a long max age. 

Do I have any options to force a browser refresh?

Despite what you've said, previously we ran a Cloudfront invalidation after any app updates and that seemed to push the latest version to our users. But for reasons beyond my understanding this isn't working now... or maybe it never did?

Comment: Also might be worth saying that the login.example.com domain is pointing to a new Cloudfront distribution, rather than us updating the files on the original.

Comment: As you mentioned, the server (CF) and it's content are new, and if you're still seeing old application, then it might be browser cache which would become too powerful with service workers that has capability to serve contents even in offline. If this is your case (indefinite cache by service worker), then you can do nothing other that changing hostname. First check the service worker behavior (i.e, invalidation mechanism used in service worker). Also the cache control header that is served by old application server.